# Datagridview with x amount of columns add an empty row

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview

I have a Datagridview that gets the column names of my table(mysql). Now i wanted to add an empty row with:

```
dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
dataGridView1.Refresh();`
```

but i get the error that says: it cant add a new row if the column is databased?

How can i do this in a different way? i wanted to add a new row and then write in the cell my new value and with clicking the entry button it should make an entry in my database table.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the user to be able to add new rows you can set `AllowUserToAddRows` of your grid to true. If you just need an empty row for some purpose, you can add it directly to the data source (`dt.Rows.Add();`).